# Why am I getting Service Unavailable Error on all CloudKit queries, HTTP 503, CloudKit error code 6

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I suddenly started getting a CloudKit errors on all record queries. The CKError.Code is 6 = "Service Unavailable." The errorUserInfo dictionary on the error is:

```
["CKErrorShouldThrottleClient": 1, "RequestUUID": B59F1738-B330-4F27-A2AE-3C95572BC9F4, "NSLocalizedDescription": Request failed with http status code 503, "CKRetryAfter":30, "CKErrorDescription": Request failed with http status code 503, "NSDebugDescription": CKInternalErrorDomain: 2022, "NSUnderlyingError": <CKError 0x60000040c060: "Service Unavailable" (2022); "Request failed with http status code 503"; uuid = B59F1738-B330-4F27-A2AE-3C95572BC9F4; Retry after 30.0 seconds>]
```

Notably, about 95% of the time in the CloudKit console for this container, I also get a message "Internal Error" when querying records. About 5% of the time I am able to see a few records in the CloudKit console:

[image: CloudKit Console Screenshot]

I have tried deleting and recreating the CloudKit entitlement. I have tried creating a new CloudKit container. Neither of these helped.

A simplified version of the code that executes the query is as below. I am using the new async CloudKit interface, but I get the same error using  `privateDB.fetch(withQuery: query)` with a completion handler.

```
let privateDB = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
let recordZoneID = CKRecordZone.default()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid = %@", uuid.uuidString)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Resource", predicate: predicate)

Task {
    do {
        let (recordResults, cursor) = try await privateDB.records(matching: query, inZoneWith: nil, desiredKeys: ["uuid", "resourceData"], resultsLimit: 5)

        guard let (recordID, result) = recordResults.first else { fatalError() }

        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        case .success(let record):
            guard let resourceAsset = record["resourceData"] as? CKAsset,
            let resourceURL = resourceAsset.fileURL,
            let resourceData = try? Data(contentsOf: resourceURL)
            else { fatalError() }

            completion(resourceData)
        }
    } catch let ckError as CKError {
        print(ckError.errorUserInfo)
    } catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
 }
```

This application was previously working and I can't pinpoint anything specific I did to break it. Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here and it started a few days ago. It seems like the problem is on the Apple server side. But Apple is reporting that iCloud Driver serves are up and running. Only some of my users are affected

Comment: Same here, same conditions.